# I find error on my godaddy panel on several days can anyone help for this error?

Tags: server

[Fri Nov 03 06:01:15.175514 2023] [authz_core:error] [pid 20303:tid 47190504412928] [client 167.99.190.254:0] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /home/eazypan/public_html/application/.env

Try To resolve my problem?

Comment: It is permission issue. Please contact your provider to give full access for you.